# Does @ModelAttribute in spring internally invoke request.getParameter()?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a legacy project containing many jsps and models. Lot of places, people have used `@ModelAttribute` to map the request parameters to the specific model class.

My question is, in the conversion of request params to model, does spring internally invoke `request.getParameter()` method? I want to prevent XSS and already have XSS filter in place. But during request params to model conversion, I don't see control coming to my overriden `getParameter()` mthod.

Comment: It uses `getParameterNames` and `getParameterValues`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For binding Spring has the [`DataBinder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.html) abstraction, for a web request that utilizes the [`ServletRequestDataBinder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/ServletRequestDataBinder.html). If you take a look at the source code you will [end up here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2be80b8fc8f1fcb148ef234bfba2821949a6ea7e/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/bind/ServletRequestParameterPropertyValues.java#L80) which shows a call to [`WebUtils.getParametersStartingWith`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2be80b8fc8f1fcb148ef234bfba2821949a6ea7e/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/WebUtils.java#L690).

If you look at the last code you will see that it uses `getParameterNames` and `getParameterValues` instead of `getParameter`.

Comment: Thanks, yes indeed - I did override getParameterValues() and verified its been invoked via WebUtils.